# How to get one distinct ListofDate column from two different tables columns SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

There are two tables `Leaves, Attendanceatd` with data.

I need to display distinct `ListofDates` and `employeeid` from these two tables having some condition that in Leave table ***approvalstatus='Approved'***  and  ***startdate / enddate*** period duration on both the tables Date column.

Table schema: **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd096/6)**

```
create table Leaves(idemp_lv int,leavedate Datetime, approvalstatus varchar(100))
    insert into Leaves values (1,'2013-04-22 00:00:00.000','Approved');
    insert into Leaves values (2,'2013-04-21 00:00:00.000','Approved'); 
    insert into Leaves values(3,'2013-04-26 00:00:00.000','Approved');
    insert into Leaves values(1,'2013-04-21 00:00:00.000','Pending'); 
    insert into Leaves values(3,'2013-04-02 00:00:00.000','Pending');
    insert into Leaves values(1,'2013-04-19 00:00:00.000','Approved');

create table Attendanceatd(idemp_at int,absentdate Datetime)
insert into Attendanceatd values(1,'2013-04-19 00:00:00.000');
insert into Attendanceatd values(3,'2013-04-02 00:00:00.000');
insert into Attendanceatd values(1,'2013-04-15 00:00:00.000');
```

Desired Output:

```
Empid ListofDate
1     2013-04-22 00:00:00.000
1     2013-04-19 00:00:00.000
1     2013-04-15 00:00:00.000
2     2013-04-21 00:00:00.000
3     2013-04-26 00:00:00.000
3     2013-04-02 00:00:00.000
```

Currently I'm trying this:

```
select ListOfDates
from 
(
 select leavedate as ListOfDates from leaves where approvalstatus='Approved' and leavedate >='20130302' and  leavedate <'20130501'
 union
 select absentdate  as ListOfDates from Attendanceatd where  absentdate >='20130302' and  absentdate <'20130501'
)t1
group by ListOfDates
```

Not able to get *employeeId* along with *ListOfDates*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need group by. This gives what you want

```
 select idemp_lv, leavedate as ListOfDates
 from leaves
 where approvalstatus='Approved' and leavedate >='20130302' and  leavedate <'20130501'
 union
 select idemp_at, absentdate  as ListOfDates
 from Attendanceatd
 where  absentdate >='20130302' and  absentdate <'20130501'
```

The [UNION applies DISTINCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) automatically (note the difference if you use UNION ALL)

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd096/16/0)

Comment: Thanks for your promp reply, yes this works fine, actually i was struggling with group by

Comment: For my knowledge  can you tell me which one is better performance wise using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` as Andrew Jansen answer also works fine

Comment: Andrew's answer takes more processing. My group by is combined into the UNION in one step.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct empid, ListOfDates
from 
(
 select idemp_lv as empid, leavedate as ListOfDates from leaves where approvalstatus='Approved' and leavedate >='20130302' and  leavedate <'20130501'
 union all
 select idemp_at as empid, absentdate  as ListOfDates from Attendanceatd where  absentdate >='20130302' and  absentdate <'20130501'
)t1
group by empid, ListOfDates
```

Should do the trick unless im missing something. Just remember that union all will be faster but result in a more instensive sql sort. Always go to the execution plan to check performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select EmpId,ListOfDates
from 
(
select idemp_lv as EmpId ,leavedate as ListOfDates from leaves where approvalstatus='Approved' 
union all
select idemp_at as EmpId , absentdate  as ListOfDates from Attendanceatd
)T1
where ListOfDates between '2013-03-02' and '2013-05-01'
group by  EmpId,ListOfDates
```